# How to code this section, any idea?

Tags: html, css

Does somebody have an idea how code this?

[image: this section]

I trying with :before, table, ul. It's immposible for me..

My code:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}

li.content:before {
  content: "2012";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: aqua;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 140px;
}

li.content {}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="content">
    <strong>Masters Degree</strong><br> Dhaka University<br>
    <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine.A wonderful
      serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: writing-mode would help ... https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EpNWKY

Comment: Where do you expect the date to be defined; is it within an element in the HTML? Is it held in an attribute-value?

Comment: In HTML. but i trying also with css because i don't have any idea..

Comment: Then you need to first work out a sensible element within which the date/time should be wrapped. I appreciate you're (almost certainly) new to this, but you do need to make an effort. You *at least* need to produce relevant HTML that we can work with, otherwise you're showing us a picture and asking us for the code. We *can* do this, but we probably won't since we don't work for free. We're happy to help (and we want to!) but it's not 'help' if we do it *all*.

Comment: wchich element i must use:
table, list or div element ?

Comment: for the semantic better rely on ul element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple idea that you can elaborate:

```css
.timeline {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 80px;
  background: grey;
  list-style: none;
}

.timeline li {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom:1px solid;
  border-top:1px solid;
  box-shadow:0 20px 0 #fff;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.timeline li:nth-child(even) {
  text-align:right;
}
.timeline li:before {
  content: attr(data-date);
  color: #fff;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 100%;
  width: 80px;
  padding:10px 0;
  background: blue;
}

.timeline li:nth-child(even)::before {
  left: 100%;
  right: auto;
}
.timeline li:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:0;
  width:0;
  right:0;
  border-left:10px solid blue;
  border-top:10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:10px solid transparent;
}
.timeline li:nth-child(even)::after {
  border-right:10px solid blue;
  border-left:none;
  right:0;
  left:auto;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul class="timeline">
  <li data-date="2012 - 2018">Some text here</li>
  <li data-date="2012 - 2018">Some text here</li>
  <li data-date="2012 - 2018">Some text here</li>
</ul>
```